# Updating a viewmodel from another viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I have two ViewModels one is attached to a main window and the other is attached to child window that is opened by clicking on a button on the main window. The child window contains a list of items and I want to select an item and display it in the main window by updating the main window viewmodel. What is the best way to accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: You asked specifically for a "best" way to do this. What defines "best" to you? It could mean fastest, simplest, easiest to understand/debug, least code, etc.

Comment: Simplest is very subjective, but I tend to base it largely on the conceptual model of the real relationship between the objects. If they are parent/child, a direct reference might be very straight forward.

Comment: In this context "best" to me means the simplest way to do it as I am very new to wpf and mvvm.

Comment: I edited my answer to list my personal choice of "best" in terms of simplest.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are any number of ways to do this.

- Pass a reference to the main/parent view model into the child and have the child call the main view model.
- Have the child view model fire an event that the parent subscribes to.
- Use a messenger/mediator to communicate between the two. The parent subscribes, the child posts the message. This provides loose coupling.
- Set the main view model up as a global service. Register it somehow. Have the child look up the service (requiring global services is a pretty common problem) and then call something on the global/common interface.

From my experience, the simplest method would be #2. Define an event on the child view model. The parent will have to look up the child (I don't know if it contains it or how your view models are constructed) and subscribe to the event.

Comment: Any of these methods could be appropriate. It depends a lot on the context. Coupling is not appropriate unless the VMs are closely and conceptually related.

Comment: Very very useful answer, my MainViewModel class was starting to look like an absolute mess. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

The standard way to communicate between ViewModels is to use Messaging of some sort.  One good implementation of this is the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/)

Here's some (random) code using the default messenger therefrom:

```
//Registering:
Messenger.Default.Register<IEnumerable<BookViewModel>>(this, true, fillSourceWith);
Messenger.Default.Register<DisplayModeEnum>(this, ChangeMainTemplates);
//with a specific "token"
Messenger.Default.Register<object>(this, MessageTokens.ClearList, o => BookSource.Clear()); 

//Sending
Messenger.Default.Send<List<BookViewModel>>(newBooks);
Messenger.Default.Send<DisplayModeEnum>(DisplayModeEnum.MediumLayout);
Messenger.Default.Send<object>(null, MessageTokens.ClearList);
```

Comment: -1. He is talking about parent/child relationship. Messaging is not good idea here.

Comment: I think messaging should be fine here.  Without messaging you'd having to couple your view models somehow.

Comment: Messaging may or may not be appropriate. It may be too complicated for this problem, but it is a good solution.

Comment: @Josh G - I agree.  There are other ways that might work equally well based on his situation.  +1 on your answer for showing others

Comment: He asked for the "best" solution, but "best" is very subjective and requires more information about his context.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it is to have some kind of reference from child to parent and to update this parent when closing the child.

Or you can have some kind of event on child and let parent listen on this event. You then raise this event when child closes.

Messaging is used when both ViewModels are logicaly unrelated.

[rant] Dont people even know basic principles of OOP or what?? [/rant]

Comment: I don't think using a messenger in this case is necessarily bad design.  It would depend on any number of factors, but sending a simple message might be a lot simpler and more effective than setting up an OO relationship between the two VMs

Comment: I think the issue is that there isn't a best practice method of doing this as part of the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few days before ;-)

Finally I used a mediator to communicate both view-models. On fact I used the Messenger from MVVM Light.

```
public void Search(object parameter)
        {
            ChildWindow window = new ChildWindow();

            SearchWindow pageSearch = new SearchWindow();

            window.Content = pageSearch;
            window.Show();

            Messenger.Default.Register<Messages.CloseWindowMessage>(this, action => this.closeWindow(action));
        }
```

After that I defined the  Message with everything I needed to know from main window:

```
public class CloseWindowMessage : MessageBase
    {
        public bool Result { get; set; }
        public Model.Selected Selected { get; set; }
    }
```

Finally the message back from the childwindow you only have to register the message with result and the object you want to get back.

You should register from the code-behind of your view to close the window.

Comment: Could you complete your example, then I can use it. Where you have used this search method? How to register to that from ViewModel. What can be sent with a message? for example, if I need a variable from the second VM, How can I get access to it in the first VM? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way to pass the message between two view models is event programming.